# Is Admob Interstitial open button valid?

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android education App where user can hold "tokens" to earn new contents and features.

I searched at Admob documentation but the information seems to be not very clear about my situation.

In case to create a button to open Admob interstitial in return of any tokens mentioned above (I'm thinking make this feature periodic), should it generate invalid traffic or break any admob rule? Anyone tried it before?

My doubt consist in the fact that it does not generate invalid clicks, it just improve the number of interstitials showed.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I don't understand that. The button should open an interstitial, and after that, the user should get some new contents, is that right?

Comment: Almost. ^^ The button should open an interstitial, and because of that, the user earn some tokens (as a prize for opening the Ad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, concerning to your reply I'm pretty sure that this is not allowed. What I can tell you for sure is that you must not reward people for clicking your ads (or even a button which shows ads).
In addition to it, this is not a "natural transition point". Read what AdMob proposes about showing interstitials: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en#some_best_practices

Comment: Thank you Bevor. It answer the doubt. 

Regards! O/